# How to configure Symfony 6 CSRF token provider for login form

Tags: symfony

I'm implementing Symfony 6 user login form by this documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#create-user-class

After trying to add CSRF token protection to `security.yaml` Im getting this error:

`Not configuring explicitly the provider for the "form_login" authenticator on "secured_area" firewall is ambiguous as there is more than one registered provider.`

This is code snippet from my `security.yaml`

```
    providers:
        users_in_memory: { memory: null }
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
            logout:
                path: app_logout
        secured_area:
            form_login:
                enable_csrf: true
```

Im not sure how to configure the `csrf` token provider. If I understand right that thats what I need to do.

Comment: The error is not related to csrf but rather a lack of a provider value for your secured_area firewall.  Just copy the stuff from the main firewall and then add enable_csrf.  Assuming you actually need two firewalls?  Not really enough information to know what else to do.  Depends on how you made the login form.  In most cases, csrf will already be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

beside adding the configuration in yaml file you have to add an input in your form, so in the twig file before the form_end add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
```

I hope it helps